# Issue With Special Characters In File Path

Tags: batch-file

I posted a question earlier today but the answers received did not solve the issue (probably an error on my part by not providing enough sample code...not to mention a few typos).  In this case, everything works just fine until I get to a filepath that has "!" or "&" in the path itself.  When there is one of these characters the characters are stripped from the path (note the rest of the path appears normal) but when the hash function is called the modified path is not found (as one would expect).  I need to prevent these characters from being stripped but also function in the case where the path has spaces or no spaces.

I know I need to use expansion (or some form thereof), just not sure as to the exact placement to get the desired effect.

---

### Code Snip

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do (  
    set filepath=%%A  
    call :filepathparse  
    call :md5hashchk  
    call :echohash  
)  
goto :eof  

:filepathparse  
for %%B in ("%filepath%") do (  
    set filename=%%~nxB  
)  
goto :eof  

:md5hashchk  
for /f "delims= " %%b in ('md5deep64.exe "!filepath!"') do set hashvalue=%%b  
goto :eof  

:echohash  
echo !hashvalue!  
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` to the start of your script.

You cannot wrap variables with exclamation marks unless you have that set. See [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more information about variable expansion in batch.

Comment: I tried adding your suggestion, but when I reach the following path, the script fails: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\A!2K\file.exe".  Note the "!" in the path.  Is there a way to deal with this using the code provided (which now includes "setLocal enableDelayedExpansion" at the beginning as mentioned)?  In the current code the path is maintained but the "!" is stripped out.

Comment: Error received: The system cannot find the path specified.

Original path (as on the filesystem): C:\directory\sub!dir\file.exe
Path as parsed by script: C:\directory\subdir\file.exe

Comment: Notice the second path has no "!" and as such the error makes sense.  What I did not understand was why the "!" was being removed from the path.  It was suggested that instead of using setlocal enable delayedexpansion and "!filename!", I just change it to "%filename%".  

That solved the initial problem, but the script still will not parse directories with "&" in them.  It gives the same error as I described above in that it strips out the & and then errors "The system cannot find the path specified".  Is there a way to deal with paths that contain "&"?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand the question - it looks like `md5deep64.exe` might be what is having trouble with the special characters, as I don't see anything in your script that could strip them out.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried running the command alone and it seems to work.  Any ideas?  C:apps\win64\md5deep64.exe "C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\CNXT_MODEM_HDAUDIO_VEN_14F1&DEV_2C06&SUBSYS_14F1000F\UIU64m.exe"
55cd79b3c381308fec4a298a81b671fc  C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\CNXT_MODEM_HDAUDIO_VEN_14F1&DEV_2C06&SUBSYS_14F1000F\UIU64m.exe

Comment: Nevermind, i broke this part of my script out and the problem seems to be rooted elsewhere in the script.  I will continue to troubleshoot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, *as it was written*, don't need the delayed expansion `!variables!`; just replace exclamation-marks by percents:

```
:md5hashchk  
for /f "delims= " %%b in ('md5deep64.exe "%filepath%"') do set hashvalue=%%b  
goto :eof  

:echohash  
echo %hashvalue%    
goto :eof
```

**EDIT**: *Response to comment*

Try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do (  
    set "filepath=%%A"
    call :filepathparse
    call :md5hashchk
    call :echohash
)
goto :eof

:filepathparse  
for %%B in ("%filepath%") do (  
    set "filename=%%~nxB"
)  
goto :eof  

:md5hashchk  
for /f "delims= " %%b in ('md5deep64.exe "%filepath%"') do set "hashvalue=%%b"
goto :eof

:echohash  
set /P "=%hashvalue%" < NUL
echo/
goto :eof
```

Comment: That solved the initial problem, but the script still will not parse directories with "&" in them. It gives the same error as I described above in that it strips out the & and then errors "The system cannot find the path specified". Is there a way to deal with paths that contain "&"?

Comment: You double quote them.  `set "hashvalue=%%b"` and then `echo "%hashvalue%"`